# pdfmake can't run ng build --pro Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, pdfmake

I got errors when I try to run ng build --prod in angular 7, I think my issue because of [pdfmake](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pdf-make) library that I have added it for making the pdf document, I try to find the solution to fix it but can't found and you can see my error in below:
ERROR in Error during template compile of 'PdfmakeService'
Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'makeDecorator' was called in 'Injectable'
'Injectable' references 'Injectable'
'Injectable' references 'Injectable'
'Injectable' references 'Injectable'
'Injectable' calls 'makeDecorator'.

Answer (score 0):

I use that pdfmake library to  export a pdf file before image compress https://github.com/cesaralcoba/angular-9-compress-img-pdf i hope can help you